# I am having issues combining `with rollup` and `GROUPING`. How to correct?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sapb1

I recently was introduced to a feature called `with rollup`.  I am adding into a report I use in Excel for trends.  Issue is, I want to have the `t0.DocDate` ordered on date from oldest to newest date.

I read an article on: http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/08/rollup-and-order-by.html

I formatted my code to be similar to the example in the article but am getting this error message after doing so: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Is there anyway to correct this error in the query? If so, it would be very much appreciated by anyone who could assist me!

My code is:

```
select  CASE WHEN GROUPING(t0.DocDate) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE T0.DocDate END AS 'DocDate',
        COUNT(T1.Itemcode) [# of Cross Sell],
        SUM(T1.Price * t1.Quantity) [Cross Sell $]

from ORDR t0 inner join RDR1 t1 on t0.DocEntry=t1.DocEntry

where t0.CANCELED <> 'Y'
and t1.U_SII_XSell = 'Y'

group by t0.DocDate WITH ROLLUP
order by GROUPING(t0.docdate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your `DocDate` to a `VARCHAR` if you wish to use `'Total'` for the rollup column value.  The column cannot be both types.

To then order it by date, and have your Total column last, you need to just add `t0.DocDate` to your `ORDER BY` clause.

```
select  CASE WHEN GROUPING(t0.DocDate) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE Cast(T0.DocDate As Varchar(15)) END AS 'DocDate',
        COUNT(T1.Itemcode) [# of Cross Sell],
        SUM(T1.Price * t1.Quantity) [Cross Sell $]

from ORDR t0 inner join RDR1 t1 on t0.DocEntry=t1.DocEntry

where t0.CANCELED <> 'Y'
and t1.U_SII_XSell = 'Y'

group by t0.DocDate WITH ROLLUP
order by GROUPING(t0.docdate), t0.docdate;
```

Comment: The only adjustment I made was from `CAST` to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t0.DocDate,101)` the `CAST` was showing some extra data I didn't need to see.  Thanks again for the advice!